# custom destructuring pattern

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a time value represented by a string of format `'hhmmss'` and want to assign a variable for each hours, minutes, and seconds.

I've tried to find a solution where I could do something neat, like

```
let [h, m, s] = '083000';
```

For now, my working solution is a little bit more verbose :

```
const str = '083000';
let [h, m, s] = [str.slice(0, 2), str.slice(2, 4), str.slice(4, 6)];
```

Is there a way to get closer to the first snippet ?

Comment: No, destructuring works on arrays. So you have to make your string a array like you do.

Comment: A string is already an array, destructuring already work on strings. My problem is the 'one item to one variable' association

Comment: http://ramdajs.com/docs/#partition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can "chunk" your string into an array of two character strings using a regex:

```
const str = '083000';
let [h, m, s] = str.match(/../g);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how guaranteed your input format is, and how self-documenting you want your code to be, personally I find this the most readable approach:

```
const str = '083000'
const [, h, m, s] = str.match(/^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/);
```

This makes it clear that you're grabbing three sets of 2 digits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1 for self documenting code, but it is already clear in my code that the input is a set of 6 digits. Also worth noting even if it does not matter for my use case, your regex is a lot slower than the one proposed by deceze.

Comment: Yup, totally fair. Regexp performance will vary a lot by engine, and since this snippet doesn't cache the regex object you never know how that will effect things.